# github API unsupported media type 415

Tags: api, http, meteor, github, github-api

I was using github API in Meteor but could not solved this issue:

This code tries to get the total number of traffic for a certain repo.

```
HTTP.call( 'GET', 'https://api.github.com/repos/hackmdio/hackmd/traffic/views', 
    {
        headers: 
        {
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            "Accept":"application/vnd.github.v3+json",
            "User-Agent": "whales"
        },
    },
    function( error, response ) {
  if ( error ) {
    console.log('---------------------------error occurred-----------------------------------')
    console.log('---------------------------error occurred-----------------------------------')

    console.log( error );
  } else {

    console.log('--------------------------data got it!!-------------------------------------')
    console.log('--------------------------data got it!!-------------------------------------')

    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

Error:

```
{
  "message": "If you would like to help us test the Repo Traffic API during its preview period, you must specify a custom media type in the 'Accept' header. Please see the docs for full details.",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

I searched for similar issues and added "Content-Type" and "Accept" but it's still not working.

I then tried doing this in Postman and also in terminal with the same headers but this error kept happening. [image]

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

You will need to add an `Accept: application/vnd.github.spiderman-preview` header to your request in order to access the Repo Traffic API whilst it is in preview form. From the [API docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/traffic/):

> APIs for repository traffic are currently available for developers to preview. During the preview period, the APIs may change without advance notice. Please see the blog post for full details.
>
> To access the API you must provide a custom media type in the Accept header:
>
> `application/vnd.github.spiderman-preview`

Comment: they tell you explicitly to do this ... but so easy to forget

Comment: Also if anyone is using any other features which are still in the developers preview its best to pick the correct value using this overview page https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/api-previews - i was using projects and i had to pick `application/vnd.github.inertia-preview`.

Answer (score 2):

To anyone who ends up on this page after googling why GitLab API has started throwing 415 when sending `POST` requests:

Make sure you pass the `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header if you're sending stuff via post-data fields. Their docs never mention this b/c apparently many clients (like `curl`) do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The Commit Search API is currently available for developers to preview. During the preview period, the APIs may change without advance notice.

To access the API you must provide a custom media type in the Accept header:

```
 Accept: application/vnd.github.cloak-preview
```

☝️This header is required.

[check docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/search#search-commits-preview-notices)